# how do i get a string from regex python

Tags: python, regex

I am not familiar with regex, can someone help me with this example?
I have a json output from python API call, the json looks like this:

```
{
  "key": "/my/task/ca4e0240d6ce447554f805e118928",
  "key2": "values"
}
```

How can i use re to find the `ca4e0240d6ce447554f805e118928` in this case?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you shouldn't use a regex to parse Json.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regex for this, you need `basename` to extract the rightmost part of path separated string:

```
import os

d = {
  "key": "/my/task/ca4e0240d6ce447554f805e118928",
  "key2": "values"
}

print(os.path.basename(d["key"]))
```

result:

```
ca4e0240d6ce447554f805e118928
```

(note that it also works on Windows, even if standard path separator is `\`)

Alternate way (still without regex), using `str.rpartition`:

```
print(d["key"].rpartition("/")[2])
```

Regex: remove everything before the slash slash (greedy):

```
print(re.sub(".*/","",d["key"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `str.split()` to have your desired output like this example:

```
a = {
  "key": "/my/task/ca4e0240d6ce447554f805e118928",
  "key2": "values"
}

print(a["key"].split("/")[-1])
```

Or if your output will have both `'/'` and/or `'\'` you can use a lambda function like this:

```
get_string = lambda x: x["key"].split("/")[-1] if '/' in x["key"] else x["key"].split("\\")[-1]

print(get_string(a))
```

Both will output:

```
'ca4e0240d6ce447554f805e118928'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you insist on using regex, it will work for both `/` and `\`, but this is completely unnecessary, and you should use the `os.path` module:

```
import re
d = {
  "key": "/my/task/ca4e0240d6ce447554f805e118928",
  "key2": "values"
}
match = re.search(r"[/|\\](\w+)$", d["key"]).groups()[0]
print(match)
```